# Infinite loop when uploading image

Tags: php, loops, printf, infinite

I want to upload images using a browse button, but when I click, an infinite loop generates. I want that every file is loaded, the name is : 001 then 002 then 003...

Here are the codes :

Index.php

```
<?php

require('class/Image.php');

if(!empty($_FILES)){
    $image = new Image();
    $images = $image->upload($_FILES);
}
if($images === true){
    $msg_success = 'Le chargement a réussi';
} else {
    $msg_error = 'Le chargement a échoué';
}

?>

<h1>Ajouter une image</h1>

<?php

if(isset($msg_success)){
    echo $msg_success;
}
if(isset($msg_error)){
    echo $msg_error;
}

?>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" value="" name="upload[]" multiple="multiple">
    <input type="submit" name="uploadFormSubmit" value="Ajouter">
</form>
```

Image.php

```
<?php

class Image{

    public function upload($files){

        $upload_dir = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Devoir/PHP/Avancé/1/images/';
        foreach($files['upload']['error'] as $key => $error){
            $error = 0;
            if(!isset($i)){
                $i = 1;
            }
            if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
                $tmp_name = $files['upload']['tmp_name'][$key];
                $name = $files['upload']['name'][$key]; 
                $tab_name = explode('.', $name);
                $format = '%1$03d';
                $file_nbr = sprintf($format, $i);
                while(file_exists($upload_dir . $file_nbr . '.' . $tab_name[1])){
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $upload_dir . $file_nbr . '.' . $tab_name[1]) == false){
                $error += 1;
            }
            if($error == 0){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now we understand what you want to achieve. What happened instead?

Comment: Nothing happen when i click on the button to add an image.

Comment: I thought the Earth is moving on its orbit, the Sun is giving light, millions of people take breath in the meantime... Nothing happens in your system? I am sure something happens. For instance you can look into your network tab or console tab of your browser to give us more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should include `$file_nbr = sprintf($format, $i);` in your while loop as well:

```
while (file_exists($upload_dir . $file_nbr . '.' . $tab_name[1])){
    $i++;
    $file_nbr = sprintf($format, $i);
}
```

Comment: I can't because $file_nbr in     file_exists($upload_dir . $file_nbr . '.' . $tab_name[1]) doesn't exist before.

Comment: Don't move it. Leave the one you've got where it is and add another as per my example. If the criteria for the while expression does not change within your loop it will be endless.